# R: why group_by still requires "do" even when using quosures

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, quosure

How to make a user-defined function work nicely with pipes and group_by? Here is a simple function:

```
 library(tidyverse)

 fun_head <- function(df, column) {
 column <- enquo(column)
 df %>% select(!!column) %>% head(1)
 }
```

The function works nicely with pipes and allows to filter by another column:

```
 mtcars %>% filter(cyl == 4) %>% fun_head(mpg)

 >    mpg
   1 22.8
```

However, the same pipe-work fails with group_by

```
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% fun_head(mpg)

Adding missing grouping variables: `cyl`
# A tibble: 1 x 2
# Groups:   cyl [1]
     cyl   mpg
     <dbl> <dbl>
1     6    21
```

Using "do" after group_by makes it work:

```
 > mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% do(fun_head(., mpg))
 # A tibble: 3 x 2
 # Groups:   cyl [3]
    cyl   mpg
   <dbl> <dbl>
1     4  22.8
2     6  21  
3     8  18.7
```

How should the function be changed so that it works uniformly with filter and group_by without needing "do"?
Or quosures have nothing do with the question, and group_by just requires using "do" because the function in the example has multiple arguments?

Comment: Note that `mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% select(mpg) %>% head(1)` also gives you just the first row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is independent of quosures. Here's the same issue in the absence of non-standard evaluation in `fun_head()`:

```
fun_head <- function(df) {df %>% select(mpg) %>% head(1)}
mtcars %>% group_by( cyl ) %>% fun_head()
# Adding missing grouping variables: `cyl`
# # A tibble: 1 x 2
# # Groups:   cyl [1]
#     cyl   mpg
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     6    21
```

As explained in other questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28447608/dplyr-from-group-by-into-own-function) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28201066/pass-grouped-dataframe-to-own-function-in-dplyr), `do` is the connector that allows you to apply arbitrary functions to each group. The reason `dplyr` verbs such as `mutate` and `filter` don't require `do` is because they handle grouped data frames internally as special cases (see, e.g., [the implementation of mutate](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/master/src/mutate.cpp#L480)). If you want your own function to emulate this behavior, you would need to distinguish between grouped and ungrouped data frames:

```
fun_head2 <- function( df )
{
  if( !is.null(groups(df)) )
    df %>% do( fun_head2(.) )
  else
    df %>% select(mpg) %>% head(1)
}

mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% fun_head2()
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
# # Groups:   cyl [3]
#     cyl   mpg
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     4  22.8
# 2     6  21  
# 3     8  18.7
```

**EDIT:** I want to point out that another alternative to `group_by` + `do` is to use `tidyr::nest` + `purrr::map` instead. Going back to your original function definition that takes two arguments:

```
fhead <- function(.df, .var) { .df %>% select(!!ensym(.var)) %>% head(1) }
```

The following two chains are equivalent (up to an ordering of rows, since `group_by` sorts by the grouping variable and `nest` doesn't):

```
# Option 1: group_by + do
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% do( fhead(., mpg) ) %>% ungroup

# Option 2: nest + map
mtcars %>% nest(-cyl) %>% mutate_at( "data", map, fhead, "mpg" ) %>% unnest
```

Answer (score 3):

As you've written it, the function selects `column` from `df`, then takes `head`, which is the first row of `df` (`head` is not a tidyverse function, and isn't aware of any grouping). `dplyr::slice(1)` takes the first row of each group, which is what you want. You can use

```
 fun_head <- function(df, column) {
 column <- enquo(column)
 df %>% slice(1) %>% select(!!column)
 }

 mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% fun_head(mpg)

# # A tibble: 3 x 2
# # Groups:   cyl [3]
#     cyl   mpg
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     4  22.8
# 2     6  21  
# 3     8  18.7
```

Comment: Does such approach happens to work here because of 'head' or it is more general? The answer given by Artem Sokolov suggests that "do" is needed with group_by

Comment: There are some other functions like `head`, which have tidyverse equivalents, like `slice`. But there are some which don't, so sometimes you need to use `do`. As mentioned in the other answer "`do` is the connector that allows you to apply *arbitrary* functions to each group", emphasis mine.